# Using sys/sem.h in C, How to get the semaphore value?

Tags: c, operating-system, semaphore

I am using sys/sem.h in C to implement semaphore, but now I am stuck with a strange problem so I want to check the semaphore value. I write such a function:

```
int sem_set(int semid, int sem_val)
{
union semun sem_union;
sem_union.val = sem_val;
if (semctl(semid, 0 , SETVAL , sem_union) == -1)  return 0;
return 1;
}

int sem_get(int semid)
{
 union semun sem_union;

 return semctl(semid, 0 , GETVAL , sem_union);
}

int sem_wait(int semid)
{
 struct sembuf sb;
 sb.sem_num = 0;
 sb.sem_op = -1;
 sb.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
 if (semop(semid, &sb, 1) == -1)
 {
  printf("error/n");
  return 0;
 }
 return 1;
}
```

But the function is going wrong when I have such two processes running:

initially sem.val is set to 0;

process1:
...
printf("%d", sem_get(sem_id));
sem_wait(semid);
...

process2:
...
printf("%d", sem_get(sem_id));
sem_wait(semid);
...

Assuming process 1 run first and executed sem_wait(semid), I guess process 2 should output -1 but actually 0 is printed. How could this happen? is my function wrong? Or the semaphore implementation in sem.h is different to what I learned in the class?

Comment: Are you making sleep in process1. Process1 should be in critical section when process2 is executig.

Comment: Note that a semaphore never becomes negative. You just block if you try to decrement (sem_wait() ) a semaphore that has the value 0, and will be woken up when someone increments(sem_post() ) the value.  sem_wait() can't decrement it unless the semaphore value is > 0

Answer (score -2, accepted):

there is already the function sem_getvalue()

here is an example

```
int sem_getvalue(sem_t *sem, int *valp);
```

strongly suggest performing a bit of googling for 'how to use semaphores in C'

one such web page is:

```
http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~mdamian/threads/posixsem.html#getvalue
```

here is an excerpt from the man page for sem_getvalue

sem_getvalue() places the current value of the semaphore pointed to sem
       into the integer pointed to by sval.